# Render partial view (with controller action) from another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, renderpartial, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a layout that contains a treeview.  The treeview is populated by an `AddressBookController` and rendered into every page with `@RenderPage("addressbook.cshtml")` (it is currently in `Shared`).  The problem with this is that I have tight coupling between the View and the Controller as in the top of my AddressBook.cshtml I have the following code:

```
@{    
    var controller = new EstateManagerUI.Controllers.AddressBookController();
    var topLevelFolder = controller.GetAddressBook(0);
}
```

How can I render the partial view FROM the controller so I can render it like a normal view?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a child action and the `Html.Action` helper. Phil Haack wrote a nice blog post about child actions here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller action that returns a `PartialViewResult`

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // do some stuff
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView", myModel);
}
```

and then render this in your page by using `@Html.Action("MyAction")`